# Generate link to clone or duplicate a post from wordpress frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

I've found a number of plugins for wordpress that add a link to the table in the backend to clone or duplicate a post or page ([Duplicate Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/), [Clone Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/clone-posts/), and [Post Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-duplicator)). This is nice, but I'm building a bit of an app on wordpress where I'm using a custom post type as an entry and would like to be able to quickly copy an entry with a link from the frontend of the site (similar to how edit_post_link works but without jumping into the backend).

I'm using Gravity Forms for the create and edit functionality for entries on the frontend, but I can't quite figure out the best approach for a secure way to submit a request, execute the clone query, and the return to the same page I was on before (i.e. not jumping into the backend). [Gravity Forms Post Updates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-post-updates/) plugin does something similar with a do_action call to generate a link. I've looked through this function and generally get what's happening, but I'm not sure if I need all of the extra plugin class structure.

I was hoping to find an example of a function that could create a secure url with a nonce and then another function we validate the url and execute the query and return to the previous page. Is this the right way to go or am I barking up the wrong tree? If so, any code samples or examples that might be able to help get me started?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found this post (http://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/duplicate-post.html) and was able to figure out what I needed to. Instead of adding a filter to include the link in the backend, I instead created an action that can be called with do_action and generates the link. I also have a page and page template that is solely for executing the call and then redirecting back to the referring url.